# How can play mp3 and its LRC file together?

Tags: music-player

```
ls music
song.lrc    song.mp3
```

`song.lrc` is the song lyrics of `song.mp3`,how can play `song.mp3` and `song.lrc` together?Listen to the music and watch the lyrics?I have tried with vlc,smplayer,audacious,clementine;all of them can play music ,not showing lyrics.

The song.lrc is in the below format:

```
[00:12.00]Line 1 lyrics
[00:17.20]Line 2 lyrics
[00:21.10]Line 3 lyrics
...
mm:ss.xxlast lyrics line
```

Comment: Does that .lrc file follow a specific file format or is it just the text of the lyrics? Where does it come from? Never heard of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/2222) exchange, `mpv` supports this out of the box, when you specify the LRC file as subtitle file, using `--sub-file`.

Comment: mpv  song.mp3  --sub-file=song.lrc